# Is there any law in India that mandates address to be published for websites that do business, specially online transactions?

Tags: contract-law, internet, india, online, payment

Is there any law that mandates that a physical address to be published for the operators of websites that do business, particularly online transactions? There are [laws that mandate a physical address](https://Are%20there%20any%20law%20that%20mandates%20address%20to%20be%20published%20on%20websites%20that%20do%20business%20specially%20online%20transactions?) for registering a company, but are there any laws that mandates a website that does financial transactions online, must have a valid physical address published on its website before running such online e-commerce business?